# Failed to verify SSH host key, please add them in SSH page in the admin interface

Tags: weblate

I created a weblate(version 2.11) and gitlab container.

Steps to reproduce

1. I clone it from https://github.com/WeblateOrg/docker.git
2. I created the weblate on the docker.
3. I open weblate with admin account
4. gen ssh key
5. past the ssh key on my gitlab page
6. created a new project
7. created a new component.
8. Source code repository: git@172.19.0.4:root/weblate-test.git

weblate `docker-compose.override.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:
    weblate:
        environment:

            - WEBLATE_SITE_TITLE=weblate
            - WEBLATE_EMAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
            - WEBLATE_EMAIL_HOST_USER=12345678
            - WEBLATE_EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=12345678
            # - WEBLATE_REQUIRE_LOGIN=1
            - WEBLATE_OFFLOAD_INDEXING=1
            - WEBLATE_TIME_ZONE=Asia/Taipei
            - WEBLATE_REGISTRATION_OPEN=1
            - WEBLATE_ALLOWED_HOSTS=dev.weblate.com
            - WEBLATE_ADMIN_PASSWORD=password
```

I tried recreate a lot of times container. I still got the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to generating client SSH key, you need to verify host keys as well. You can do that on the very same interface in Weblate, see [documentation](https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/vcs.html#ssh-repositories).

Comment: I used the admin page to gen ssh-key and past to my private gitlab(I created own). Not work for me

Comment: Okay, let's solve this in one place only: https://github.com/WeblateOrg/weblate/issues/1372